# How can I embed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Report Builder into my forms?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reportbuilder

I don't want to open Report Builder from Report Manager. I want to embed Report Builder into my forms. Is there any way?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very old topic, but I want to post a correct answer since it's one of the first results when searching for "Report Builder".

Simply add a WebBrowser control to your form and on Form_Load, navigate to the URL of the Reporting Services server. You'll have a no-frills "browser" - no back button, no stop, no refresh, but right-clicking on the page will do it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe report builder uses anything other than the SSRS API to do its work. You will need to create your own report builder. One way to do this is to play with the microsoft one and monitor the traffic between your browser and the server with HTTPAnalyser or Fiddler. Then you can recreate the same web service calls fom your own app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the Report Builder standalone installer?  v2.0 was just released in April, so it's possible that you haven't seen it.  You can find it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=dbddc9b6-6e19-4d4b-9309-13f62901b0d5&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do this, given that the Report Builder 2.0 is a standalone application

What you could do however is create a shared data source on the server, and avail the link to the setup file for the installer in your application. Users can then connect to the data source and depending on their skill, create their own reports.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to subscribe to the appropriate service and build out a front end to talk to the service.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Reporting Services is more of a server based reporting solution.  If my embedding into your forms you mean that you want the end user to build reports from inside your application I suggest you look at a third-party tool to do this.  I use Developer Express controls and they have a strong and reasonably priced solution for this.  The product page is [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/features_enduserdesigner.xml).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easy.
You can drag Microsoft.ReportViewer control from toolbox to your webform in studio 2008.
Then you can open report builder to initialize your report.
At the end, that report can be viewed and exported when you run your report.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a hyperlink in your app to startup the click once Report Builder app. But it won't run within your form.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795295.aspx for info on constructing the correct URL.

Paul